# In office 2013 can v2003 files be retained in their original 2003 format?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-office-2003

So far I have been using Office 2003 and I have lots of .xls files created in 2003 version.

Will they open seamlessly in Office 2013 and remain as 2003 format files? That’s how I want it to be but not sure if it will work that way. I understand that newer versions of office uses different formats like .xlsm .docx etc.

Is there any setting to retain 2003 as 2003 files in Office 2013?   I shall be moving quite a few files between my laptop and desktop and as of now desktop has Office 2003 only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was surprised to discover that this isn't a duplicate. Good question!

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there any setting to retain 2003 as 2003 files in Office 2013?

Save your Excel worksheets as "Excel 97-2003 Workbook":

> You’ve upgraded to Excel 2016, and realize you’ll be sharing workbooks
>   with people who haven’t upgraded yet. Running the Compatibility
>   Checker can help you identify features or information that might not
>   be available in an earlier version, so you can resolve some of those
>   issues before you share your workbook.
>
> The Compatibility Checker runs automatically when you save a workbook
>   to Excel 97-2003 (*.xls) format. You can also run it yourself if you
>   are sharing with someone who's using Excel 2013, 2010, or 2007.
>
> **Save a
>   file to .xls format and review Compatibility Checker issues**
>
> 1. Click File > Export.
> 2. Under Export, click Change File Type.
>
>    [image: Change File Type on the Export tab]
> 3. Under Workbook File Types, double-click Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls).
>
>    [image: Excel 97-2003 Workbook format]
> 4. In the Save As dialog box, pick the location for the workbook.
> 5. In the File name box, type a new file name or use the one that’s already there.
> 6. Click Save.
> 7. If the Compatibility Checker appears, review the compatibility issues it found.
>
>    [image]
>
>    The Find link takes you to that place in your worksheet. The Help
>      link takes you to information on the issue and possible solutions.
>
> Notes:
>
> - In Excel 2016, the workbook you just saved in .xls format opens in Compatibility Mode. Keep working in this mode when you plan to send
>     this workbook back and forth to people who open it in the earlier
>     version of Excel.
> - When you’re done with the backward compatibility, click File > Info > Convert to convert the workbook to the current file format so
>     you can take advantage of any new Excel 2016 features.

Source [Save an Excel workbook for compatibility with earlier versions of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Excel-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-169a0336-965b-4430-8554-4e7b5db79947?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)